# C#/.Net Library that can draw a line across the date line

Tags: c#, .net, dotspatial

I want to be have an embedded map in my application that can handle drawing lines across the date line. I have tried out dotspatial and sharpmap and neither have been able to handle this.

Edit: Here is an early example of the kind of information that would need to draw over the date line https://i.stack.imgur.com/05NBC.jpg Please excuse the very low res map product.

The software needs to support loading custom map products via geotiffs or something similar.

This is a c# winforms application.

Answer (score 1):

What sort of application?  We support this in [MapDotNet](http://www.mapdotnet.com), but only for shapes less than half the width of the globe.  It requires setting the TestForCrossingMaximumExtents flag on our Map object, which isn't exposed in our Studio UI and must be set in code (when using our Silverlight or WPF controls) or by editing mapfile XML manually.

Comment: The software is generating a strip map for airplane navigation. It needs to be able to draw custom symbols that can be rotated and contain text.

Here is an example (with a very low res map product) http://imgur.com/B3Fg7R5

Comment: The software is a C# winforms application.

Comment: Ah... we might be out of luck, then.  We'll still want to draw the map from -180 at the left to + 180 at the right (max limits), it sounds like you might really need to render the area from +160 at the left to +200 (= -160) at the right.  That could be done with our product, but you'd have to dig pretty deeply into our object model and extend some of our classes.

Comment: Also, we support WPF but you'd have to embed WPF into an old-school winforms app.

Comment: Thanks, but yes we would need to be able to take snapshots at zoomed in locations with rotations to match the path traveled.

Comment: Rotation is a trivial problem.  It's the need to effectively change the prime meridian that would get tricky.